# Retrieve data from possibly broken HDD

Tags: hard-drive, external-hard-drive, hardware-failure, hard-drive-recovery

My younger sister accidently dropped my Inspiron n5010 from her lap. Since then whenever I try to boot it I get this -

> A disk read error occured.

My first guess was a broken HDD, so I used a SATA to USB interface to connect the HDD to my other computer and it won't detect it, and even if it does (happens rarely), I can't access it, it hangs my Windows Explorer.

I suspect mechanical damage to the drive. While there could be another cause for this trouble, this one seems the most likely to me.

I had some data on that drive that I'd like to recover. Is there a way to do so?

Comment: Data recovery companies exist.  They remove the platters in a clean room and put them inside a working drive.  If it's a mechanical problem there is nothing you can do specifically.  If the data is that valuable, recover the data, then practice good backup practices

Comment: Regular and redundant backups should be your religion

Comment: @Ramhound yes they do exist, unfortunately not in my city, so I was looking for a kind of DIY solution

Comment: There no "do it yourself" solutions to remove and replace HDD platters.

Comment: @Ramhound well then all my data is best forgotten?

Comment: There are companies that will allow you to ship your HDD to them, they will perform their work, then send you the data back if they have success.

Comment: @Ramhound I've tried looking for every possible professional help that I can get but I found none. There might be a lot of companies but none are here.

Comment: There are no companies near me either, which is the reason I put it the HDD in a box, and ship it to them.  I don't understand how you can say your unable to find data recovery companies, when even Seagate and Western Digitail, offer those services.

Comment: @Ramhound I can't ship stuff buddy... By the time the drive goes all through the process of recovery I'll rebuild the data I lost. I am in a bit of hurry